# ImportError: No module named nltk macos

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, nltk

Starting on a Python chatbot and using anaconda followed a tutorial and could not import nltk, using pytorch as well.

```
import nltk 
#nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
stemmer = PorterStemmer()

def tokenize(sentence):
    return nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)

def stem(word):
    return stemmer.stem(word.lower())



def bag_of_words(tokenized_sentence, all_words):
    pass

a = "How long does shipping take?"
print(a)
a = tokenize(a)
print(a)
```

The error after attempting to import nltk

```
(pytorch) jack.s@McUnicorn-Pro-2 Chatbot % python nltk_utils.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nltk_utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk 
ImportError: No module named nltk
(pytorch) jack.s@McUnicorn-Pro-2 Chatbot %
```

Comment: Have you installed `nltk` on the anaconda environment ? Can you share the modules already installed ? you can do it with `conda list` once you're in the environment.

Comment: `nltk                      3.5                        py_0 ` 

Yes I have it installed in the environment but then when I enter `conda list` it does not show that I have it installed in my PyTorch environment. @BradFigueroa

Comment: @JackSimpson _when I enter conda list it does not show that I have it installed in my PyTorch environment._ That's likely the issue, then.